# Can't pass 'greater than' or 'less than' operators in reportFilters via url

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, filters, custom-reports

I have a lightning component that redirects to a custom report passing filters via url. This component is working inside a community and, as far as I know, you need to generate your url with a 'reportFilters' url parameter.

This parameter is an encoded string based on a JSON with this structure:

**[
{'operator' : 'equals',
 'value' : value,
 'column' : columnName},
{...}
]**

The point is that if I try putting an operator different from 'equals' it tells me that kind of value for operator doesn't exist although is referenced in salesforce documentation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_operators.htm&type=5).

Does anyone know how can I implement this or if it's a salesforce limitation?

**EDIT**

The fields that need to have this operator are datetime fields parsed as String (CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate). Maybe I need to pass them as date values instead of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should actually use `greaterthan` or `lessthan`. You also have `lessthanorequal` and `greaterthanorequal`. You cannot use `>` or `<` directly because that implies starting or ending of tag. Also you should not really use `==` as a best practice. Instead you should be using `equals`.

**In [Expression Functions Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm), you will find all the function names that can be used.**

---

**NOTE**

If you need `<` or `>` in value, you can set it in javscript controller.

Example:

cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="myUrl" type="String" default="" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

{!myUrl}
```

JS:

```
doInit : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.myUrl", "https://www.some.url.with_>_and_<_works_Fine_Here");
},
```

Comment: Hi, I also tried `greaterthan` and `lessthan` but receiving the same error message (non valid operator)

Comment: added solution for your prob

Comment: Hi, I just find out that the operator is case sensitive and although it says that you can use 'greaterthan' or 'lessthan' you must use 'greaterThan' and 'lessThan' instead.

Comment: capitals will not work. its all small,

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that the issue was with the operator value declaration. It needs to be 'greaterThan' and 'lessThan' instead of 'greaterthan' and 'lessthan' although sf documentation doesn't say so.

Comment: `greaterThan` will not even compile

Comment: `Failed to save POC_AURA.cmp: c:POC_AURA:9,3: No function found for key: greaterThan: Source`